# Ongoing chance of drawing a particular number from a bag of numbers

Tags: probability

I'm sure this question has been asked many times over applied in different ways so perhaps there is a duplicate question that can simply be pointed to.

Let's say there is a bag with 10 numbers in it (1 through 10).  Assume that after each time a number is drawn, that number is put back into the bag so there are always 10 numbers to choose from.

The chance of me drawing a specific number is obviously always going to be 10% for any given attempt.  But how would I calculate the chance of drawing a particular number for x number of attempts in this scenario?

EDIT:  Just to make sure I'm being completely clear here let me retell the scenario in a slightly different way.  Suppose there are x number of bags and each one contains 10 numbers (1 through 10).  What is my chance of drawing a 5 from one of the bags if I draw from each bag exactly once?

Comment: Hint: what is your chance of *not* drawing that number after $x$ attempts?

Comment: @whuber My chance of not drawing for any given attempt is 90%.  But over x attempts I don't know.  I wish I did, because then I'd know the answer to my question as well :)

Comment: @whuber Actually I just realized you said *after* x attempts.  I was thinking *over* at first.  So the answer to that would be 90%.  But my question isn't about the chance *after*, but rather *over* x attempts.  Perhaps these two things are related in a way I don't understand?

Comment: Let $x=2$ for instance. The chance of not observing a 5 in the first draw is $9/10$.  The chance of not observing 5 in the second draw is $9/10$.  Because the draws are physically independent and the contents of the bag are the same each time, the results are statistically independent.  Therefore the chance of *both* outcomes is the product $9/10\times 9/10$.  Consequently the chance that you *did* draw a 5 at least once within $x=2$ attempts equals $1 - (9/10)^2$.  (You are correct that this analysis has appeared before on our site, but it's going to be hard to search for it... .)

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I'm sure if I'd known even the most basic fundamentals of statistics then your hint would have greatly helped... but unfortunately it's been over a dozen years since I've taken any kind of math course and it hasn't stuck with me :)

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Two_events) might help. Incidentally, if you're trying to model sampling with replacement, *dice* are the more common model for the process. [Imagine a ten-sided die](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Orange,_10-sided_die.jpg) ...